# What is the best way to end a task to prevent run-away

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I have created the function below which would wait for all the tasks to complete or raise an exception when a cancellation or time-out occurs.

```
public static async Task WhenAll(
    IEnumerable<Task> tasks, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    int millisecondsTimeOut)
{
    Task timeoutTask = Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeOut, cancellationToken);
    Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(
        Task.WhenAll(tasks), 
        timeoutTask
    );
    if (completedTask == timeoutTask)
    {
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
}
```

If all the `tasks` finished before a long time-out (i.e. `millisecondsTimeOut` = 60,000), would `timeoutTask` be staying around until 60 seconds has elapsed even after the function returns?  If yes, what is the best way to fix the runaway problem?

Comment: It will hang around but is really lightweight.  As long as you don't have hundreds of these hanging around, you probably won't see a difference if you let it run to completion. You could however create a `CancellationTokenSource` in your method, pass that `CancellationToken` to the `Task.Delay`.  At the end of your method, just cancel that token which will kill the delay.

Comment: Well, if this is being invoked 100s of times per second than this can be very significant overhead. You are risking exploding memory usage. This is a timed memory leak. Will not be found during testing. It makes the application unreliable.

Comment: What's the purpose of the function? As a signalling mechanism, or to pause the main (or monitoring) thread while the worker threads execute? If you just want to kill all the worker threads, then you have the `CancellationTokenSource`, so just use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `timeoutTask` would hang around until that timeout is over (or the `CancellationToken` is canceled).

You can fix it by passing in a different `CancellationToken` you get from a new `CancellationTokenSource` you create using `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource` and cancelling at the end. You should also await the completed task, otherwise you aren't really observing exceptions (or cancellations):

```
public static async Task WhenAll(
    IEnumerable<Task> tasks,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    int millisecondsTimeOut)
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeOut, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(tasks), timeoutTask);
    if (completedTask == timeoutTask)
    {
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }

    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    await completedTask;
}
```

However, I think there's a simpler way to achieve what you want, if you don't need to distinguish between a `TimeoutException` and `TaskCancelledException`. You just add a continuation that is cancelled when the `CancellationToken` is cancelled or when the timeout is over:

```
public static Task WhenAll(
    IEnumerable<Task> tasks,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    int millisecondsTimeOut)
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
    cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(millisecondsTimeOut);

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(
        _ => _.GetAwaiter().GetResult(), 
        cancellationTokenSource.Token,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, 
        TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate on why you added `await completedTask` at the end?  I thought `Task.WhenAll` would wait for all the tasks to be either completed, canceled, or got exception.  If the function returns due to timeout, it would be the responsibility of caller for cancelling/ending the tasks or performing other works.

Comment: Because `Task.WhenAny` has the signature `Task<Task>`, the 2nd await is to observe the result of the inner task so if it did throw a exception its exception could be propagated up the call stack.

Comment: @Tony `Task.WhenAll` throws an exception if one of its tasks throws an exception... `Task.WhenAny` doesn't. If you want the caller to know there was an exception you need to await the completed task and have the exception rethrown.